# How to do user level access control using traefik

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I am new to traefik, previously I use nginx to do reverse proxy with simple access control

```
server {
    ...
    auth_basic "Auth";
    auth_basic_user_file conf/htpasswd;
}
```

Is it possible to do in traefik? really like the cool GUI provided by traefik

Plan to deploy it into kubernetes, the application itself doesn't has access control